# Impact of error "running state does not match what SharePoint expects: FIMSynchronizationService."

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service

Can someone explain what's the actual impact of the error:

> The following services are managed by SharePoint, 
>       but their running state does not match what SharePoint expects: FIMSynchronizationService.

Specifically, what I'm interested in is, can this error cause slowness of SharePoint to be experienced by the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific question, FIMSynchronizationService working or not does not affect performance of SharePoint. It doesn't, however, mean that *same issue* causing *this* specific error wouldn't cause slowness, but it doesn't seem likely (considering the following chapters below).

FIMSynchronizationService is responsible for synchronizing user profile properties from Active Directory to SharePoint User Profile service and runs in the background.

What has happened is that someone has most probably Started or Stopped the FIM Windows Service manually using Services application in Windows. This should not be done as SharePoint wants to control this and only starts/stops the two services when the Synchronization is configured successfully and UPS service is started/stopped from SharePoint Central Admin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If FIMSynchronizationService impacts User Profile Service, will this in turn slow down specific assets like My Sites?

Comment: No, FIMSynchronizationService only syncs data between AD and User Profile Service, it isn't, e.g., called when user enters MySite, or views user profiles. 

User Profile Service itself may have issues meaning that all user profile queries (even fetching user name for the Name menu you see top right on all pages) take long time to load, making all pages load slow.

Comment: Thanks guys for taking the time to explain. I will accept this answer. Feel free to add more information.